# virsh net-define for CoreOS cluster

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, coreos

I have a kvm/qemu/libvirt host with several VMs running happily on br0 with IP addresses that are in the same network as the host they run inside, 192.168.10.0/24.

So I'm playing with CoreOS and following their cluster guide [Running CoreOS on libvirt](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-libvirt.html) as closely as possible. When I attempt to user their `deploy_coreos_libvirt.sh` script, it can't find the virtual network "default." Indeed there is no virtual network defined according to `virsh net-list`. 
My Ubuntu 14.04.4 host has no example network/default.xml file but my CentOS 7 kvm host does. Again, both machines have no virtual networks defined. Below is the example network/default.xml from CentOS 7.

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <bridge name="virbr0"/>
  <forward/>
  <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

So if my physical lab network is 192.168.10.0/24, what network should I use for my virtual network? The user_data example on the CoreOS page has "Network": "10.1.0.0/16". Should I use that in the virtual network config?

Answer (score 0):

I defined a new virtual network from this xml

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <bridge name="br1"/>
  <forward/>
  <ip address="192.168.11.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.11.2" end="192.168.11.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Once I defined br1 (net-define) and activated it (net-start), deploy_coreos_libvirt.sh had no problem building me three new CoreOS VMs. Had to use `arp -a` to figure out their IP addresses, but that was no biggie. Would be nice if there was a virsh command that would do that.

I can get in and out of these new VMs as easily as if they were on my LAN's native network. Nice.